# How to put the picture in the left side of my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

How to put the picture in the left side of my navbar?
I can't seem to understand how it works- the picture is going up and the navbar is outside the div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
}

#logo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="navbar"> <img class="logo" src="logo.gif">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#none">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Game Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Gameplay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Media</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't add your code in comments pls, have added the snippet for you..

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
#navbar{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to use flexbox, you may try this:

```css
favorite body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  /*****************/

  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  
  /*****************/
}

#logo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="navbar"> <img width="40" class="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/apple.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#none">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Game Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Gameplay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Media</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Access class logo by '.'

2-apply positioning to class logo as i applied and set height and width of class

3- set width of  also
 heres my code

```css
favorite body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  /*****************/
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  
  /*****************/
}

.logo {
  position :relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 27%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="navbar"> <img width="40" class="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/apple.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#none">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Game Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Gameplay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Media</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
down vote favorite body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
}

#logo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="navbar"> <img class="logo" src="logo.gif">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#none">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Game Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Gameplay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#none">Media</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
   ul {
        list-style: none;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```